# @Options keyword in Vue 3 app generated by Vue CLI

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vuejs3

In Vue3 documentation,  @Options keyword is nowhere explained. But it is used, as shown below, in the getting-started CLI project. Even though its purpose can be guessed, can anyone please explain this keyword?

@Options({
components: {
HelloWorld
}
})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not explained in Vue documentation because it is not a Vue 3 API

You probably told the Vue CLI to generate the project with support for [class-style syntax](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#vue-cli-setup)

This installs separate library called [Vue Class Components](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component). [Here is the documentation](https://class-component.vuejs.org/) for a version of this library used with Vue 2

Unfortunately the version for Vue 3 (in the [next branch](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/tree/next)) is in beta stage and has no documentation yet

> The documentation is not ready yet. But you can see [v8 proposals in the issue list](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Av8)

From the [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/406) it seems `@Options` is replacement for previous `@Component`

Comment: Thank you very much, Michal, for clarifying my doubts

Comment: This is about the closest thing to an explanation for all of the confusion around Vuejs 3 vs 2, Vuejs with Typescript vs Javascript, `@Component`, `@Options`, Composition API, Options API, function API, etc.  All of the stuff appears to under the VueJS umbrella, but it's really a composite of many projects all by different authors and maintained rather haphazardly.  Which wouldn't be an issue if was easier to understand the boundaries of each project.  Vue-cli doesn't help newbies understand this because it pre-packages all of this stuff both helpfully and unhelpfully.